# Why does ctypes.c_int completely change its behaviour when put into ctypes Structure?

Tags: python, ctypes

When I create a variable of type `ctype.c_int` it reports that type and does not allow any math operations:

```
In [107]: x = c_int(1)
In [108]: x
Out[108]: c_int(1)
In [109]: x+=1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
----> 1 x+=1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'c_int' and 'int'

In [110]: x+=x
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
----> 1 x+=x
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'c_int' and 'c_int'

In [111]: type(x)
Out[111]: ctypes.c_int
```

On the other hand: when I make a structure with `c_int` inside it is reported as `int`, allows math operations but still seems to be stored as 32-bit c-integer because it wraps correctly on 32 bit, and honors sign bit at position 31.

```
In [112]: class REC(ctypes.Structure): _fields_=[('x',ctypes.c_int),('y',ctypes.c_int)]
In [113]: rec = REC()

In [114]: rec.x
Out[114]: 0

In [114]: type(rec.x)
Out[114]: int                       # why not ctypes.c_int ???

In [116]: rec.x+=0x7FFFFFFF         # += works, so it is regular python int ?

In [117]: rec.x
Out[117]: 2147483647

In [118]: rec.x+=1

In [119]: rec.x
Out[119]: -2147483648               # but it honors sign bit at position 31...

In [122]: rec.x=0xFFFFFFFF

In [123]: rec.x
Out[123]: -1

In [124]: rec.x+=1

In [125]: rec.x
Out[125]: 0                         # ...and it wraps on 32 bits, so it is NOT python int!
```

Can someone explain this behavior? Is there any logic behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bare `c_int` has to have two **identities**: the C object whose `addressof` may be taken, and the Python object `x`.  The former is an integer, but the latter is not.  (Recall that `x=2` would just rebind `x` and would not update the C integer.)

When you put the variable in a structure, `ctypes` can provide, as a **convenience**, an attribute-based interface that converts between the C and Python representations.  This has its own surprises: store a suitably large value and you’ll see that then `rec.x is not rec.x`.  The manufactured objects are real Python objects, but of course they don’t follow Python **rules** since they don’t own any data.

The same applies to the bare integer’s `value` attribute.

Oddly enough, it’s [hard to get](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50531131/8586227) the equivalent of a bare integer from a structure, so you can’t easily pass a structure member to a function to fill it in.