# ctypes How to get address of NULL c_void_p field?

Tags: ctypes

I need to get the address of a NULL void pointer. If I make a NULL c_void_p in Python I have no problem getting its address:

```
ptr = c_void_p(None)
print(ptr)
print(ptr.value)
print(addressof(ptr))
```

gives

```
c_void_p(None)
None
4676189120
```

But I have a

```
class Effect(structure):
    _fields_ = [("ptr", c_void_p)]
```

where ptr gets initialized to NULL in C. When I access it in python

```
myclib.get_effect.restype = POINTER(Effect)
effect = myclib.get_effect().contents
print(effect.ptr)
```

gives `None`, so I can't take `addressof(effect.ptr)`.

If I change my field type to a pointer to any ctype type

```
class Effect(structure):
    _fields_ = [("ptr", POINTER(c_double)]

# get effect instance from C shared library
print(addressof(effect.ptr))
```

I have checked that I get the right address on the heap on the C side

```
140530973811664
```

Unfortunately, changing the field type from c_void_p is not an option. How can I do this?

**Clarification**

Here's C code following @CristiFati for my specific situation. struct is allocated in C, I get a ptr back to it in Python, and now I need to pass a reference to a ptr in the struct. First if I make the ptr a double, there's no problem!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PRINT_MSG_2SX(ARG0, ARG1) printf("From C - [%s] (%d) - [%s]:  ARG0: [%s], ARG1: 0x%016llX\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, ARG0, (unsigned long long)ARG1)

typedef struct Effect {
    double* ptr;
} Effect;

void print_ptraddress(double** ptraddress){
    PRINT_MSG_2SX("Address of Pointer:", ptraddress);
}

Effect* get_effect(){
    Effect* pEffect = malloc(sizeof(*pEffect));
    pEffect->ptr = NULL;
    print_ptraddress(&pEffect->ptr);
    return pEffect;
}
```

And in Python

```
from ctypes import cdll, Structure, c_int, c_void_p, addressof, pointer, POINTER, c_double, byref
clibptr = cdll.LoadLibrary("libpointers.so")

class Effect(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("ptr", POINTER(c_double))]

clibptr.get_effect.restype = POINTER(Effect)
pEffect = clibptr.get_effect()

effect = pEffect.contents
clibptr.print_ptraddress(byref(effect.ptr))
```

gives matching addresses:

From C - [pointers.c] (11) - [print_ptraddress]:  ARG0: [Address of Pointer:], ARG1: 0x00007FC2E1AD3770
From C - [pointers.c] (11) - [print_ptraddress]:  ARG0: [Address of Pointer:], ARG1: 0x00007FC2E1AD3770

But if I change the double* to void* and c_void_p, I get an error, because the c_void_p in python is set to None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after raising this in the python bug tracker, Martin Panter and Eryk Sun provided a better solution.

There is indeed an undocumented `offset` attribute, which allows us to access the right location in memory without having to do any introspection. We can get back our pointer using

```
offset = type(Effect).ptr.offset
ptr = (c_void_p).from_buffer(effect, offset)
```

We can more elegantly wrap this into our class by using a private field and adding a property:

```
class Effect(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("j", c_int),
                ("_ptr", c_void_p)]
    @property
    def ptr(self):
        offset = type(self)._ptr.offset
        return (c_void_p).from_buffer(self, offset)
```

I have added an integer field before our pointer so the offset isn't just zero. For completeness, here is the code above adapted with this solution showing that it works. In C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PRINT_MSG_2SX(ARG0, ARG1) printf("%s : 0x%016llX\n", ARG0, (unsigned long long)ARG1)

typedef struct Effect {
    int j;
    void* ptr;
} Effect;

void print_ptraddress(double** ptraddress){
    PRINT_MSG_2SX("Address of Pointer:", ptraddress);
}

Effect* get_effect(){
    Effect* pEffect = malloc(sizeof(*pEffect));
    pEffect->ptr = NULL;
    print_ptraddress(&pEffect->ptr);
    return pEffect;
}
```

In Python (omitting the above Effect definition):

```
from ctypes import cdll, Structure, c_int, c_void_p, POINTER, byref
clibptr = cdll.LoadLibrary("libpointers.so")

clibptr.get_effect.restype = POINTER(Effect)
effect = clibptr.get_effect().contents
clibptr.print_ptraddress(byref(effect.ptr))
```

yields

```
Address of Pointer: : 0x00007F9EB248FB28
Address of Pointer: : 0x00007F9EB248FB28
```

Thanks again to everyone for quick suggestions. For more, see [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue35390?@ok_message=msg%20331074%20created%0Aissue%2035390%20message_count%2C%20messages%20edited%20ok&@template=item):

Comment: What an idiot am I ..... I used `CField.offset` in the answer that included as a reference in my answer :)))))

Answer (score 1):

*ctypes* ([[Python 3]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes)) is meant to be able to "talk to" *C* from *Python*, which makes it *Python* friendly, and that means **no pointers, memory addresses, ... whatsoever** (well at least as possible, to be more precise). 
So, under the hood, it does some "magic", which in this case stands between you and your goal.

***@EDIT0***: Updated the answer to better fit the (clarified) question.

Example:

> ```
> >>> import ctypes
> >>> s0 = ctypes.c_char_p(b"Some dummy text")
> >>> s0, type(s0)
> (c_char_p(2180506798080), <class 'ctypes.c_char_p'>)
> >>> s0.value, "0x{:016X}".format(ctypes.addressof(s0))
> (b'Some dummy text', '0x000001FBB021CF90')
> >>>
> >>> class Stru0(ctypes.Structure):
> ...     _fields_ = [("s", ctypes.c_char_p)]
> ...
> >>> stru0 = Stru0(s0)
> >>> type(stru0)
> <class '__main__.Stru0'>
> >>> "0x{:016X}".format(ctypes.addressof(stru0))
> '0x000001FBB050E310'
> >>> stru0.s, type(stru0.s)
> (b'Dummy text', <class 'bytes'>)
> >>>
> >>>
> >>> b = b"Other dummy text"
> >>> char_p = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)
> >>> s1 = ctypes.cast((ctypes.c_char * len(b))(*b), char_p)
> >>> s1, type(s1)
> (<ctypes.LP_c_char object at 0x000001FBB050E348>, <class 'ctypes.LP_c_char'>)
> >>> s1.contents, "0x{:016X}".format(ctypes.addressof(s1))
> (c_char(b'O'), '0x000001FBB050E390')
> >>>
> >>> class Stru1(ctypes.Structure):
> ...     _fields_ = [("s", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char))]
> ...
> >>> stru1 = Stru1(s1)
> >>> type(stru1)
> <class '__main__.Stru1'>
> >>> "0x{:016X}".format(ctypes.addressof(stru1))
> '0x000001FBB050E810'
> >>> stru1.s, type(stru1.s)
> (<ctypes.LP_c_char object at 0x000001FBB050E6C8>, <class 'ctypes.LP_c_char'>)
> >>> "0x{:016X}".format(ctypes.addressof(stru1.s))
> '0x000001FBB050E810'
> ```

This is a parallel between 2 types which in theory are the same thing:

1. `ctypes.c_char_p`: as you can see, *s0* was automatically converted to *bytes*. This makes sense, since it's *Python*, and there's no need to work with pointers here; also it would be very annoying to have to convert each member from *ctypes* to plain *Python* (and viceversa), every time when working with it. 
   Current scenario is not part of the "happy flow", it's rather a corner case and there's no functionality for it (or at least I'm not aware of any)
2. `ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)` (named it *char_p*): This is closer to *C*, and offers the functionality you needed, but as seen it's also much harder (from *Python* perspective) to work with it

The problem is that `ctypes.c_void_p` is similar to ***#1.***, so there's no *OOTB* functionality for what you want, and also there's no `ctypes.c_void` to go with ***#2.***. However, it **is** possible to do it, but additional work is required.

The well known (*C*) rule is: 
    ***AddressOf(Structure.Member) = AddressOf(Structure) + OffsetOf(Structure, Member)*** (**beware** of *memory alignment* who can "play dirty tricks on your mind").

For this particular case, things couldn't be simpler. Here's an example:

*dll.c*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#if defined(_WIN32)
#  define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define DLL_EXPORT
#endif

#define PRINT_MSG_2SX(ARG0, ARG1) printf("From C - [%s] (%d) - [%s]:  ARG0: [%s], ARG1: 0x%016llX\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, ARG0, (unsigned long long)ARG1)


static float f = 1.618033;

typedef struct Effect {
    void *ptr;
} Effect;


DLL_EXPORT void test(Effect *pEffect, int null) {
    PRINT_MSG_2SX("pEffect", pEffect);
    PRINT_MSG_2SX("pEffect->ptr", pEffect->ptr);
    PRINT_MSG_2SX("&pEffect->ptr", &pEffect->ptr);
    pEffect->ptr = !null ? NULL : &f;
    PRINT_MSG_2SX("new pEffect->ptr", pEffect->ptr);
}
```

*code.py*:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from ctypes import CDLL, POINTER, \
    Structure, \
    c_int, c_void_p, \
    addressof, pointer


DLL = "./dll.dll"


class Effect(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("ptr", c_void_p)]


def hex64_str(item):
    return "0x{:016X}".format(item)


def print_addr(ctypes_inst, inst_name, heading=""):
    print("{:s}{:s} addr: {:s} (type: {:})".format(heading, "{:s}".format(inst_name) if inst_name else "", hex64_str(addressof(ctypes_inst)), type(ctypes_inst)))


def main():
    dll_dll = CDLL(DLL)
    test_func = dll_dll.test
    test_func.argtypes = [POINTER(Effect), c_int]

    effect = Effect()
    print_addr(effect, "effect")
    test_func(pointer(effect), 1)
    print(effect.ptr, type(effect.ptr))  # Not helping, it's Python int for c_void_p
    try:
        print_addr(effect.ptr, "effect.ptr")
    except:
        print("effect.ptr: - wrong type")
    print_addr(effect, "effect", "\nSecond time...\n    ")
    print("Python addrs (irrelevant): effect: {:s}, effect.ptr: {:s}".format(hex64_str(id(effect)), hex64_str(id(effect.ptr))))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Output**:

> ```
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q053531795>call "c:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2015\vc\vcvarsall.bat" x64
>
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q053531795>dir /b
> code.py
> dll.c
>
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q053531795>cl /nologo /DDLL /MD dll.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:dll.dll
> dll.c
>    Creating library dll.lib and object dll.exp
>
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q053531795>dir /b
> code.py
> dll.c
> dll.dll
> dll.exp
> dll.lib
> dll.obj
>
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q053531795>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> effect addr: 0x000001FB25B8CB10 (type: <class '__main__.Effect'>)
> From C - [dll.c] (21) - [test]:  ARG0: [pEffect], ARG1: 0x000001FB25B8CB10
> From C - [dll.c] (22) - [test]:  ARG0: [pEffect->ptr], ARG1: 0x0000000000000000
> From C - [dll.c] (23) - [test]:  ARG0: [&pEffect->ptr], ARG1: 0x000001FB25B8CB10
> From C - [dll.c] (25) - [test]:  ARG0: [new pEffect->ptr], ARG1: 0x00007FFFAFB13000
> 140736141012992 <class 'int'>
> effect.ptr: - wrong type
>
> Second time...
>     effect addr: 0x000001FB25B8CB10 (type: <class '__main__.Effect'>)
> Python addrs (irrelevant): effect: 0x000001FB25B8CAC8, effect.ptr: 0x000001FB25BCC9F0
> ```

As seen, the address of *effect* is the same as the address of *effect*'s *ptr*. But again, this is the simplest possible scenario. But, as explained a general solution, is preferred. However that's not possible, but it can be worked around:

- Use the above formula and get the field offset using [[SO]: Getting elements from ctype structure with introspection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50304516/getting-elements-from-ctype-structure-with-introspection/50310152#50310152) (it's long, I had a hard time coming to the current solution - especially because of the 2 container types (*Structure* and *Array*) nesting possibilities; hopefully, it's bug free (or as close as possible) :) )
- Modify the *C* interface to something like: `Effect *get_effect(void **ptr)`, and store the address in the parameter
- Modify the (*Python*) *Effect* structure, and instead of `ctypes.c_void_p` field have something that involves *POINTER* (e.g.: `("ptr", POINTER(c_ubyte))`). The definition will differ from *C*, and semantically things are not *OK*, but at the end they're both pointers

**Note**: don't forget to have a function that destroys a pointer returned by *get_effect* (to avoid *memory leaks*)

Comment: Thanks! Of course the effect structure actually has many more fields, and it's important for our application that things be machine independent, so I don't think adding a fixed offset is an option. I guess I can write a wrapper function in C that takes the void pointer and passes on its address, but I assumed that I was missing something and that there must be a simple way of getting the address from python. I still don't quite see why that's not possible for a c_void_p but is for other types.

Comment: No one mentioned adding a fixed offset. "*I still don't quite see why that's not possible for a c_void_p but is for other types*" Again, wrong statement. In the interpreter  copy / paste at the beginning, i showed the same thing for *c\_char\_p*. And it applies for **all** types.

Comment: I've clarified what I mean above with code and how it works with POINTERS of ctypes but not c_void_p (I think you're right also not for c_char_p). What I'm saying is that one way to get around it like you said would be to pass byref(pEffect) but since in the real struct (which I can't reorganize) there are more members before the void*, I'd have to add an offset. And I don't think I can do that in a machine independent way right? (Due to padding)

Comment: Thanks, I think only the third would work for me. How reliable would that be? The C standard explicitly does not guarantee that void * will be the same size as other pointers (except char*). I still don't see why this should not be possible. Doesn't ctypes need to keep track of the C memory addresses internally? Shouldn't the address of the c_void_p exist somewhere?

Comment: To be frank I didn't encounter cases where 2 pointers have different sizes (in the same executable, of course). Yes *ctypes* stores the *C* addreses internally, but for this case (*c\_\*\_p* types in containers) it just happens that it doesn't exposes them to *Python*.